# Background menu colors

Tags: gnome, menu

After fiddling around installing themes and icons and stuff, aslo usign the gnome configurator, I now have the background of my top menu white - how do i restore it to the original ubuntu theme color?

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiz installed, do this

1. Open Compiz config Setting manager - (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type ccsm and press enter)
2. Go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin section
3. Go to Experimental category
4. There you can change panel opacity to desired value (or reset to default by clicking on last button in that field)

If you don't have `compiz(ccsm)` installed, you can also change panel behavior using other softwares like MyUnity but I recommend installing ccsm

**UPDATE**: Install MyUnity software to change settings easily regarding panel, dash etc.:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install myunity
```

Comment: mmh my menus are actually gray (solid gray) and I want them back to default ubuntu config... no issue with opacity for me! thanks!

Comment: ok.plz check my updated comment

Comment: I have it but I think I ned some advanced tool... if i change theme, the background for my menus keeps staying greyish O__o

Comment: have you tried resetting to default setting as well?

Comment: where can i find the default reset switch?

Comment: In every section , in the top you will find default settings

Comment: it unfortunately doesnt work :( I have my menus with grey back ground and slightly darker text... O__o